# Ubuntu 20 with NGINX add subdomain for existing IP

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have a small app written with NodeJS and it is hosted in Google Cloud. I reserved a IP and I can access the front of app with IP.

The problem is, I have an admin panel witch it is a different Node instance. This has his own port and I want to access it via url, like: **http://admin.11.111.11.11**

**I've using NGINX with Ubuntu 20.4**

Config for admin it looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        #server_name admin.11.111.11.111/ www.admin.11.111.11.111/;
        location / {
                #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2222;
        }
}
```

and for front:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111;
        }
}
```

At this moment I can't transfer the domain. I must wait client to finish writing his content. The mydomain.com use an old CMS so we must wait to finish to transfer the content, **so the new app it is accessible just through new IP.**

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

> This has his own port and I want to access it via url, like: http://admin.11.111.11.11

No, this isn't possible `admin.11.111.11.11` is not a valid hostname.  You can't mix hostnames and IP addresses as the host like that.  This whole premise is flawed... this isn't an Nginx problem.

Comment: I see. Ok, thank you! I will use other domain until we finish content transfer.